# NVIDIA Control Panel not available on Windows Server

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce, windows-server-2019

Per Microsoft request, NVIDIA removed their GFX Control Panel from their driver packs and now it is available only in the Microsoft Store. (See [this support article](https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4733/%7E/nvidia-control-panel-windows-store-app).)

Since I currently use Windows Server, I do not have Access to the Microsoft Store. I contacted NVIDIA Support and they said that my GeForce GT-710 card does not officially support Windows Server, and there are no drivers for server OS (even though Windows 10 64-bit drivers are fully compatible with Server 2019).

Older driver packs are not compatible with Server 2019 anymore because of the error:

> Your system requires DCH Compatible driver package.

Any idea how I can get NVIDIA Control Panel working on Windows Server?
(Or how to install apps from the Microsoft Store on Windows Server?)

Comment: What do you need access to in the Nvidia control panel that you can't get to through Windows itself? Have you looked at how to install apps via powershell?

Comment: I Need to set the Default output to HDMI monitor: https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/forums/geforce-graphics-cards/5/148294/setting-default-output-when-booting-computer/

Comment: Regard installing apps from powershell, I found this : Add-AppxPackage, but it works only if I can get the .APPX file, and it should be signed... (I'm not sure if OS is part of its signature)

Comment: I am doubtful that changing primary displays will have an effect on the UEFI display pre-boot. In my experience the display that shows the UEFI is impossible to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-DCH drivers with NVIDIA Control Panel can be found [here](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/Find.aspx?lang=en-us).